# SAPUI5: I can't assign custom control properties inside XML views or inside the controller

Tags: sapui5

I have a custom control with two properties, I want to assign Json data to one of them in XML View, but it is not possible, I can **only** assign value via defaultValue property.
The Control metadata:

```
sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/Control", 
 "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
 "sap/ui/core/HTML"
 ], function(Control, JSONModel, HTML) {
  return Control.extend("QuickInfo.QuickInfo", {

    metadata : {
        properties : {
            "template" :    { type : "string" },
            "dataTable" :   { type : "sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel" } 
        },
        aggregations : {
            _oHtml : { type : "sap.ui.core.HTML", multiple: false, visibility: "hidden" }
        }
    }
  });
});
```

And I want to assign the dataTable property in the XMLView:

```
<QuickInfo dataTable="{quickInfoModel1}"/>
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you can consider object and not JSONModel

```
"dataTable" :   { type : "object" }
```